# react-konva How to set stage width and height to be equal to its container?

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas, konvajs

I want to set the stage width and height to be equal to it's div container, in my case, it's the div with className "drawing-area"

```
const Canvas = props => {
    return <Row>
        <Col xs={12} className="canvas-container">
            <div className="drawing-area">
                <Stage width={450} height={200}>
                    <Layer>
                        <BoxSurface/>
                        <UserText text={props.text}/>
                        <DesignImage image={props.image}/>
                        <Handler image={props.image}/>
                    </Layer>
                </Stage>
            </div>
        </Col>
    </Row>;
};
```

Because when I set width and height fixed like above, when the screen size is changed, the layout will be broken.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does the example on their github `<Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>` not work?

Comment: @Tony: no, it will set the size of stage to be equal to the size of window

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is simple. Get container size from DOM, then update stage with that size. Recalculate size of DOM element (and stage) when required.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    stageWidth: 1000
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkSize();
    // here we should add listener for "container" resize
    // take a look here https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/resizeobserver
    // for simplicity I will just listen window resize
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.checkSize);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.checkSize);
  }

  checkSize = () => {
    const width = this.container.offsetWidth;
    this.setState({
      stageWidth: width
    });
  };
  render() {
    const radius = this.state.stageWidth / 2;
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          width: "50%",
          border: "1px solid grey"
        }}
        ref={node => {
          this.container = node;
        }}
      >
        <Stage width={this.state.stageWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
          <Layer>
            <Circle x={radius} y={radius} radius={radius} fill="red" />
          </Layer>
        </Stage>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/8k2m333m92
Also take a look at this comment - https://github.com/konvajs/konva/issues/321#issuecomment-377459992

Comment: What would the example with React hooks in a functional component look like e.g. with useEffect() ?